# api-platform hydra:totalItems wrong with universal groupBy filter/extension

Tags: symfony-3.4, api-platform.com

I'm using api platform 2.2 and symfony 3.4.

I've created a custom filter (and then extension to verify if its the same behaviour) to **group by** results depending on post parameter. I'm getting the right amount of results but incorrect numbers in pagination/hydra:totalItems.

Example - shows 2nd page of results despite having no results. If i query 1st page Im getting the one single result (expected) and the same count (15603) and links to pagination.

[image]

It looks like the pagination numbers are being set before I add my groupBy to query builder in either extension or customer filter. Anyone got idea on how to fix that?

Comment: It is still THE question for API platform 2.6! :(